# Why i get multiple records for same zone in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This is Table result from procedure

```
1   4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
2   4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
3   4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
4   4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
5   4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
6   4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
7   4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
8   4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
9   4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
10  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
11  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
12  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
13  29  Delhi   1   0
14  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
15  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
16  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
17  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
18  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
19  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
20  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
21  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
22  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
23  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
24  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
25  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
26  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
27  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
28  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
29  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
30  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
31  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
32  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
33  4   Uttar Pradesh   32  1
```

I want to show Only one record from One ZONE

```
  This is my Stored Procedure,

ALTER PROC [dbo].[SUMMARY_DETAIL_USER]
--   SUMMARY_DETAIL_USER 1,10,'0',''
@PAGENO     INT, 
@PAGESIZE   INT, 
@NAME       VARCHAR(50),
@SEARCH_NAME   VARCHAR(50)

AS
DECLARE @ZONE_ID INT, @count_proj int,@count_prop int

create table #temp
    (
        SNO             INT IDENTITY,
        ZONE                INT,
        CITY_NAME           VARCHAR(50),
        COUNT_CITY_PROJECT  int ,
        PROPERTY_COUNT      int
    )
IF(@NAME = '0')
BEGIN



    INSERT INTO #temp(ZONE)
    SELECT PROJ.ZONE FROM PROJECTS PROJ LEFT JOIN PROPERTIES PROP ON PROJ.ZONE = PROP.ZONE_ID
    UPDATE #temp SET CITY_NAME=(SELECT Zone_Name FROM Zone_Master WHERE Zone_ID = #temp.ZONE)
    UPDATE #temp SET COUNT_CITY_PROJECT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROJECTS  WHERE Zone = #temp.ZONE)
    UPDATE #temp SET PROPERTY_COUNT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROPERTIES  WHERE ZONE_ID = #temp.ZONE)
    SELECT * FROM #TEMP 
    SELECT LAT, LONG,STATUS,PROJECT_NAME,PROJECT_CODE FROM PROJECTS WHERE ZONE IN (SELECT ZONE FROM #temp)
    --Select @count_proj    = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROJECTS WHERE 
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP

END

ELSE
BEGIN


    INSERT INTO #temp(ZONE)
    SELECT PROJ.ZONE FROM PROJECTS PROJ LEFT JOIN PROPERTIES PROP ON PROJ.ZONE = PROP.ZONE_ID 
    UPDATE #temp SET CITY_NAME=(SELECT Zone_Name FROM Zone_Master WHERE Zone_ID = #temp.ZONE)
    UPDATE #temp SET COUNT_CITY_PROJECT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROJECTS  WHERE Zone = #temp.ZONE)
    UPDATE #temp SET PROPERTY_COUNT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROPERTIES  WHERE ZONE_ID = #temp.ZONE)
    SELECT * FROM #TEMP WHERE CITY_NAME LIKE '%'+@NAME+'%'enter code here
    SELECT LAT, LONG,STATUS,PROJECT_NAME,PROJECT_CODE FROM PROJECTS WHERE ZONE IN (SELECT ZONE FROM #temp)`enter code here`
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP 
END
```

Comment: Did you try using `distinct`?

Comment: You join Projects with properties. If you run `SELECT PROJ.ZONE, PROP.* FROM PROJECTS PROJ LEFT JOIN PROPERTIES PROP ON PROJ.ZONE = PROP.ZONE_ID` you get a perfect view why you get multiple rows...

Comment: using distinct i got the result

Answer (score 1):

use GROUP BY PROJ.ZONE

```
INSERT INTO #temp(ZONE)
SELECT PROJ.ZONE 
FROM PROJECTS PROJ 
LEFT JOIN PROPERTIES PROP ON PROJ.ZONE = PROP.ZONE_ID
GROUP BY PROJ.ZONE
```

Answer (score 0):

You are joining `PROJECTS` with `PROPERTIES`. A project might have more than one property. When you `JOIN` two tables, a record will appear for every pairs meeting the join criteria in the result set, therefore if you have a project, which has 10 properties, the project will be repeated ten times. You need to use a `GROUP BY` clause, like @user3420762 described correctly (+1).